# How to execute su in the middle of a shell script and continue the rest of the script?

Tags: shell-script, ssh, su

```
#!/bin/bash
USERNAME=abcds
HOSTS="abcde fghij klmno pqrst aksjd ajsdf"
SCRIPT="su - admin;hostname;ulimit -u;ulimit -n"
for HOSTNAME in ${HOSTS} ; do
    ssh -l ${USERNAME} ${HOSTNAME} "${SCRIPT}"
done
```

**su** in above script does not work and displays an error: **standard in must be a tty**

Any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

use `-t` key with `ssh` in oder to allocate tty

Comment: I tried -t; su works but it doesn't continue further, stops there.